# Next/previous buttons to add in a modal

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, button

Totally new in this world, but i just love it, and i want to get the best out of it.
I am making my own photosite and i am stuck here with the next/previous button in modal. What to do?

```html
<img id="myImg" src="myimage" alt="wjuuuu" width="760" height="478">


<!-- The Modal -->
<div id="myModal" class="modal">
  <span class="close">×</span>
  <img class="modal-content" id="img01">
  <div id="caption"></div>
</div>

<script>
// Get the modal
var modal = document.getElementById('myModal');

// Get the image and insert it inside the modal - use its "alt" text as a caption
var img = document.getElementById('myImg');
var modalImg = document.getElementById("img01");
var captionText = document.getElementById("caption");
img.onclick = function(){
    modal.style.display = "block";
    modalImg.src = this.src;
    captionText.innerHTML = this.alt;
}

// Get the <span> element that closes the modal
var span = document.getElementsByClassName("close")[0];

// When the user clicks on <span> (x), close the modal
span.onclick = function() {
    modal.style.display = "none";
}

</script>
```

Comment: I don't understand what you want to do, there is no "previous" nor "next" button in your HTML. And what should happen when clicked ?

Comment: i would like tike to add the next and the previous arrows to this html I already created. but i dont know how.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of re-doing something like this, why not try something that works?  In doing something very similar to what you want to do, I used the [Blueimp gallery](https://blueimp.github.io/Gallery/).  It was simple to set up, and the previous / next buttons work, including using the arrow keys and on mobile.

Comment: Thanks a lot....I will try to use the Blueimp gallery and see what i will get out of it.

Answer (score 0):

As suggested by Steve Cochrane, better to use some libraries to achieve what you want to do but if you just plan to play with HTML and Javascript, your previous/next buttons should work exactly like the close button.

1. Give their DOM element an ID
2. Retrieve the DOM element by ID in script
3. Attach a click listener
4. Perform the logic behind previous or next action

```html
<img id="myImg" src="myimage" alt="wjuuuu" width="760" height="478">


<!-- The Modal -->
<div id="myModal" class="modal">
  <span class="close">×</span>
  <img class="modal-content" id="img01">
  <div id="caption"></div>
  <span id="previous">&lt;</span>
  <span id="next">&gt;</span>
</div>

<script>
// Get the modal
var modal = document.getElementById('myModal');

// Get the image and insert it inside the modal - use its "alt" text as a caption
var img = document.getElementById('myImg');
var modalImg = document.getElementById("img01");
var captionText = document.getElementById("caption");
img.onclick = function(){
    modal.style.display = "block";
    modalImg.src = this.src;
    captionText.innerHTML = this.alt;
}

// Get the <span> element that closes the modal
var span = document.getElementsByClassName("close")[0];

// When the user clicks on <span> (x), close the modal
span.onclick = function() {
    modal.style.display = "none";
}

// Get the previous button
var previous = document.getElementById('previous');
previous.onclick = function() {
  /* your logic here */
}

// Get the next button
var next = document.getElementById('next');
next.onclick = function() {
  /* your logic here */
}
</script>
```

Since we don't know where the images come from, we can't implement the previous and next functions for you. Hope that helps.

Comment: I will try to do the Blueimp gallery as Steve suggested. 
Thanks anyway for the help, I really appreciate it.